# Java web application : handling a blocking operation

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, struts2

We have a Java web application running on Apache Tomcat as web server and Struts 2.5 as the framework. We have a couple of web services exposed as part of this project. One of the web service has the following flow :

1. Client calls web service WS1
2. Server receives WS1 and then internally sends a push notification to a User US1
3. US1 receives the notification on his phone and takes one of the couple of actions available to him. He has maximum 60 seconds to do so.
4. Server responds to WS1 based on input from the user.

So, as we can see , we have a blocking operation in WS1. The service can take upto 60 seconds for the user to respond and hence (I believe) block one of the available Web Server threads. Now this may still work on lower loads, but it will choke the tomcat threads on Higher loads. Also, unfortunately, this entire workflow is the crux to the solution and for the sake of this discussion, lets please assume that I cannot change this workflow.

I am trying to understand what are my options around solving a potential bottleneck. Is there a way that I can somehow change this to asynchronous operation and/or ensure that Web Server threads are better utilized? Also, is my assumption correct that Tomcat will be blocking a thread for 60 seconds in this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand why this would be blocking if the user is making an HTTP request back to indicate their choice. Just sounds like you need a way to track that 60 second limit.

Comment: What framework are you using for web services? Each framework has its own way to put the request into _"asynchronous mode"_.

Comment: This is very unclear. In which way the user input is provided while you block him/her from the main thread? How the main thread should know if the input been provided? Before posting a question like this make sure you have prepared [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As I understand, you can't change the design; therefore, you probably should look at increasing Tomcat core thread pool size and go for a horizontally scaled deployment if it is a high load environment, simplest might be put multiple Tomcats behind load-balancer and configure sticky/non-sticky sessions as might be required.